# Random semicolon in collections

Tags: bug, status-completed, collectives, collections

For some reason, there's a random semicolon in Collections. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/collections/76822323/r-answers-that-need-review) is what I'm referring to.

[image]

[image]

I'm assuming it shouldn't be there and is a mistake, so can this random semicolon be removed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. The extra semicolon was removed.